# using selenium webdriver I am not able to identify the hidden < href > element

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

```
  <li class="rktpage">
drop a Conmerce
<ul style="visibility: hidden;">
<li class="">
<a href="/dom_config/ui/loc/insert">rtw By user</a>
</li>
```

I am facing difficulty to   identify “rtw By user” href element which is under  “drop a Conmerce” tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to click on hidden element in Selenium WebDriver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110282/how-to-click-on-hidden-element-in-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110282/how-to-click-on-hidden-element-in-selenium-webdriver - is it your problem?

Comment: Hi, by using driver/webdriver you can't interact with hidden elements. you need to use javascript executor to interact with hidden elements. please look into links provided above.

Answer (score 0):

To find text

```
 driver.findElements(By.tagName("li")).get(index_of_li_tag).getText();
```

To find href attribute value

```
driver.findElement(By.id("li")).get(index_of_li_tag).getAttribute("href");
```