# Xpath of invisible element

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to find Xpath of invisible element in IE as my web page doesn't work in firefox.
I want to click "Select' link which is available in table format .
Class name and href are not unique

Comment: <TD class=data></TD>
<A class=decision href="javascript:revoke('01214345987')">select</A>
</TD>

Comment: What do you mean by invisible element here??

Comment: opacity of element is zero

Comment: would you please provide at full HTML structure where you want to locate as well..

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is designed in a way not to allow interaction with hidden elements.(if a user can't click, why should Selenium?).

What you can try is to make Selenium execute a script (Java/Python/Javascript/etc.) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110282/how-to-click-on-hidden-element-in-selenium-webdriver) or  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363038/selenium-webdriver-click-on-hidden-elements)