# Selenium: Wait For a Hidden Input Field to Appear

Tags: selenium, webdriver-io

Here is a snippet of Selenium test code that runs okay:

```
    it("The 1st shop should have 10 items", function() {
    return browser
        .url(cdpUrl)
        .waitForVisible('#slider0')
        .elements('#slider0 img').then(function(res) {
            expect(res.value.length).to.equal(10);
        });
    });
```

But what I want to do instead is replace the `waitForVisible` line with one that looks for a hidden input field with `id='documentReady'` that is dynamically inserted into the page when the page preparation is complete.

I've tried numerous things but none of them work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `waitForExist`?

Comment: @Robert W.   have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110282/how-to-click-on-hidden-element-in-selenium-webdriver) for hidden elements