# Count Of Hidden Rows in WebTable By Using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy, katalon-studio

I have a hide button in the application that hides duplicate data entries on web table. I have been trying to capture the number of hidden rows. See html and my approaches below. Every attempt I have tried ended up with **0**. However, the result should be **2**.

**HTML CODE:**

```html
<tbody>
<tr role = "row" class="odd">...<tr/>
<tr role = "row" class="even">...<tr/>
<tr role = "row" class="odd">...<tr/>
<tr role = "row" class="even">...<tr/>
<tr role = "row" class="odd">...<tr/>
<tr role = "row" class="odd duplicate" style="display: none;" >...<tr/>
<tr role = "row" class="even duplicate" style="display: none;" >...<tr/>
</tbody>
```

```
def getInvisibleTableRowCount()
{
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody"))
    List<WebElement> rows_table= table.findElements(By.cssSelector("[display=none]"));
    int rowSize = rows_table.size();
    return rowSize;
}
```

**Here is my other attempt:**

```
def getInvisibleTableRowCount()
{
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody"))
    List<WebElement> rows_table= table.findElements(By.tagName("tr[not(contains(@style,'display: none;'))]"));
    int rowSize = rows_table.size();
    return rowSize;
}
```

If I ran the xpath as //*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[not(contains(@style,'display: none;'))] , I can find the hidden rows on the browser.

**I have also tried this:**

```
def getInvisibleTableRowCount()
{
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody"))
    List<WebElement> rows_table= table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    int rowSize = rows_table.size();
    for(WebElement row: rows_table)
    {
        if(row.isDisplayed()==false)
        {
            rowSize = rowSize -1; 
        }
    }
    return rowSize;
}
```

After @Hac's comment, I tried JQuery. I ran the jQuery on browser, it works with no problem. But I get a "NULL" value returned in my function. I double checked the jQuery string that prompts correct in the comment line.

```
@Keyword
def getTableRowCountAfterHiding()
{
    def jQuery='$'+'("#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr:visible").length'
    WebUI.comment(jQuery);
    def visibleRowCounts = new utils.ExecuteJavaScript().executeJavaScript(jQuery);
    return visibleRowCounts;
}
```

I defined utils to run JS as it is in below:

```
public class ExecuteJavaScript {
    //This keyword is designed to execute JS.
    @Keyword
    def executeJavaScript(String javascript) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) DriverFactory.getWebDriver()).executeScript(javascript)
    }
}
```

Comment: Selenium was designed to not interact with hidden elements to mimic a person interacting with the site. I suggest checking the total number of visible ones before and after instead. Or you could use javascript to force the interaction with hidden elements. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22110282/6205848

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have been struggling with this. I will try to execute JS.

Comment: I tried to execute JS, no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This worked:**

```
def getTableRowCountAfterHiding()
{   
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    List<WebElement> table = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[not(contains(@style,'display: none;'))]"))
    int rowSize = table.size();
    return rowSize;
}
```