# Is there a way to use Selenium to bypass clicking "Accept Cookies" on the cookies pop-up and click the "Add to Cart" button behind it?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

So I'm testing a bot I've created using Python with Selenium on the Amazon website.

When the bot opens the browser on the Amazon product page, I'm greeted with a "Select Your Cookies Preference" slide-up pop-up at the bottom of my window.

I can use my Selenium bot to click the "Accept Cookies" button and then click the "Add to Cart" button, which I coded without any issues - but my question is, can I bypass clicking the "Accept Cookies" button and go straight to clicking the "Add to Cart" button behind this Cookies slide-up pop-up?

I know I can click on "Add to Cart" without hitting "Accept Cookies" when I manually use the website, but can my bot do this? If so, how? Because I tried to use my bot to click the "Add to Cart" button without clicking the "Accept Cookies" button, but the website wasn't registering the click (even with an implicit wait) - but it works fine when I code the bot to click the "Accept Cookies" button first and then click the "Add to Cart" button.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Because I tried to use my bot to click the "Add to Cart" button without clicking the "Accept Cookies" button, but the website wasn't registering the click (even with an implicit wait)  - show us the code for this part, error stack trace

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming here that due to the "Accept Cookies" pop-up, the "Add to Cart" button is hidden. If you can find the hidden element (Add to Cart btn), than use the following Stackoverflow link to click on a hidden element.

[How to click on hidden element in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110282/how-to-click-on-hidden-element-in-selenium-webdriver/22125510)