# How to interact with a hidden element using Serenity-BDD

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, serenity-bdd, serenity-platform

What I want to achieve in my `Performable` is very simple, but I can't do it due to a hidden element.

I want my actor to:

- Click on an `<input>` element
- Enter a `string` into that element
- Then hit `<RETURN>`

My current code is:

```
public class Set {
    public static Performable dateFrom(String date) {
        return Task.where("{0} set 'dateFrom' filter to " + date,
            Click.on(SearchPage.dateTimePicker_from),
            Enter.theValue(date).into(SearchPage.dateTimePicker_from)
            .thenHit(RETURN)
        );
    }
}
```

The exact error I receive when running the test is `[main] ERROR  -     Expected enabled element was not enabled`.

I found that this is due to the `<input>` element being hidden (but there is a `<div>` element "in-front" of this `<input>`)

How can I click a hidden element within my Task, without requesting a change from my Dev team?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with `JavaScriptClick`?

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you mean? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110282/how-to-click-on-hidden-element-in-selenium-webdriver)
Is there not a neater that takes advantage of the BDD style language?

Comment: I meant to use JavaScriptClick.on(SearchPage.dateTimePicker_from) which actually behind is doing the same.